# Catch only the payload of CDC in Pyspark structured streaming?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, cdc

- I'm trying to do a pipeline from SQL Server to Pyspark to catch data change in SQL Server, I have everything in place:

  - Enabling CDC in SQL Server
  - producing from SQL Server to Kafka and consuming from a Kafka topic in Pyspark structured streaming.
- The problem is: when I try to check if the data changes are going through Kafka with a console consumer it shows me the message in JSON format split into two  records: Schema and Payload and inside Payload there is Before and After which gives you the data before the change and the data after the change respectively.

  - I'm only intreated in the payload-->After  part of this JSON message

    - because when I stream it like this, in the Jupyter command line shows null on the fields that I need which I understand because the JSON format is complicated
  - Here is my pyspark code:

```
     import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = f'--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 pyspark-shell'

import findspark

findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import time

kafka_topic_name = "test-spark"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = '192.168.1.3:9092'

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka and Message Format as JSON") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Construct a streaming DataFrame that reads from TEST-SPARK
df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
    .load()

print("Printing Schema of df: ")
df.printSchema()


df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")
df1.printSchema()

 schema = StructType() \
        .add("name", StringType()) \
        .add("type", StringType())

df2 = df1\
        .select(from_json(col("value"), schema)\
        .alias("records"), "timestamp")
    df3 = df2.select("records.*", "timestamp")

  print("Printing Schema of records_df3: ")
    df3.printSchema()

 records_write_stream = df3 \
        .writeStream \
        .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds') \
        .outputMode("update") \
        .option("truncate", "false")\
        .format("console") \
        .start()
    records_write_stream.awaitTermination()

    print("Stream Data Processing Application Completed.")
```

- Here is an image showing the CDC msg arriving in Kafka:

[image]

- If anyone knows how to consume only the Payload-->After part in Pyspark Structured streaming please help me.

Comment: Please share your pyspark code from when you connected to your kafka streaming instance to where you shared in your question

Comment: @ggordon it's done, please if you have any suggestion help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your Debezeium connector to have `value.converter.schemas.enabled=false`, then you'd only have the `payload` field to consume.

Otherwise, you can either create a class/schema for that whole object along with `from_json()` function , or keep the value as a String and use `get_json_object()` Spark function to parse through the data

Also relevant - you might want to extract the [NewRecordState](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/event-flattening.html)

Answer (score 0):

-After searching more, i found out how to display and catch only the payload part of the CDC msg.

- You need to add this to your Worker.properties:

```
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```